# NSTableView Troubles

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, nstableview

I'm working on learning Objective-C/Coaoa, but I've seem to have gotten a bit stuck with getting the NSTableView object to work for me. I've followed all the directions, but for some reason I still get this error:

```
Class 'RobotManager' does not implement the 'NSTableViewDataSource' protocol
```

Here's my source, tell me what you see is wrong here, I'm about to tear my face off.

RobotManager.h

```
@interface RobotManager : NSObject {
 // Interface vars
 IBOutlet NSWindow *MainWindow;
 IBOutlet NSTableView *RobotTable;
 NSMutableArray *RobotList;
}

- (int) numberOfRowsInTableView: (NSTableView*) tableView;
- (id) tableView:(NSTableView *) tableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(int)rowIndex;
@end
```

RobotManager.m

```
#import "RobotManager.h"

@implementation RobotManager

-(void) awakeFromNib {
 // Generate some dummy vals
 [RobotList addObject:@"Hello"];
 [RobotList addObject:@"World"];
 [RobotTable setDataSource:self]; // This is where I'm getting the protocol warning
 [RobotTable reloadData];
}

-(int) numberOfRowsInTableView: (NSTableView *) tableView {
 return [RobotList count];
}

-(id) tableView:(NSTableView *) tableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(int)rowIndex {
 return [RobotList objectAtIndex:rowIndex];
}

@end
```

I'm running OS X 10.6.1 if that makes any difference. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try changing the declaration of the `@interface` to the following:

```
@interface RobotManager : NSObject <NSTableViewDataSource> {
```

This will tell the compiler that the `RobotManager` class follows the `NSTableViewDataSource` protocol.

**Edit:**

In addition, it's probably likely that the `RobotList` is not being initialized before the two methods of `NSTableViewDataSource` are being called. In otherwords, `awakeFromNib` is not being called.

Unless there is an explicit call to the `awakeFromNib` from some caller, the `RobotList` won't be initialized, so rather than populating the `RobotList` in that method, try populating it when the `RobotManager` is first instantiated.

Comment: This got rid of the warning, but data still isn't showing up in the NSTableView.

Comment: Nakedsteve: You haven't created an array and put it in the `RobotList` variable. That variable holds `nil`. So you're sending your `addObject:` messages to `nil`, which does nothing, and asking for the count of `nil`, which returns 0.

Comment: Yep, that did it. I added `RobotList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];` and now its working great. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 8):

For one thing, the data source methods now deal with `NSInteger`s, not `int`s.

More relevantly, if your deployment target is Mac OS X 10.6 or later, then you need to declare your data source's class as conforming to [the `NSTableViewDataSource` *formal* protocol](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSTableDataSource_Protocol/) in your class's `@interface`. (This protocol and many others are new in 10.6; previously, they were informal protocols.)